# Flow type and merging json objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, flowtype

Assume code of the following kind (e.g. using lodash or explicitly like here):

```
function extend(base, overwrite) {
    for (var key in overwrite)
        base[key] = overwrite[key];
    return base;
}

var first = extend({
    a: 1
}, {
    b: 2
});

var second = extend({
    c: 3
}, {
    d: 4
});

console.log(first.a + first.b + second.c + second.d);
```

How can I explain to Flowtype that this is actually fine?

Comment: What exactly are the restrictions you are attempting to apply? This doesn't actually look like very type-safe code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's javascript. Type-safety doesn't have any business here.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - the goal is to keep an utility function like extend as general as possible while making the types of first and second as strongly as possible, e.g. {a: number, b: number} and {c: number, d: number}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this just above function declaration:

```
declare function extend<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B
```